# The proper usage of "putative"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage

I'm trying to write the sentence,

> Lower-grade soldiers made up two-thirds of the putative high quality army.

My original sentence was:

> Lower-grade soldiers made up two-thirds of *what was supposed to be* a high quality army.

To make the sentence more efficient and more suitable for a formal paper, I tried looking up one word that would fit in there and came up with *putative*. Am I  using the word properly?

I was also considering *reputed*, but the definition of putative ("*commonly regarded as being: the putative father*") seemed to fit better for what I'm trying to get at.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

“... The putative high quality army” is grammatically incorrect, while  “... the *[putatively](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/putatively#Adverb)* high quality army” is grammatically correct but clumsy or misleading.  A phrasing like “Lower-grade soldiers made up two-thirds of what was, putatively, a high quality army” would be slightly less awful.  Your original sentence with “what was supposed to be” would be a better choice than any of the phrasings with  *putatively*.  However, you might also consider using a near-synonym, *[ostensibly](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ostensibly#Adverb)*:  “Low-grade soldiers made up two-thirds of an ostensibly high-quality army”.

Comment: +1 I agree with every single point. I think you would sooner use *putative* immediately before a noun (not before another adjective), where the noun expresses a status that can be disputed.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider simply using "supposedly" in that sentence. If you want something more fancy "purportedly" is another possibility that may be closer to the meaning you want.